# Exception has occurred: TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

im new to selenium and ive got this time excpetion error... do give me a solution

why is there a timeout exception

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
contact = "Trisha Chirkoot"
text = "Hey, this message was sent using Selenium"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\insignia projs\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")
print("Scan QR Code, And then Enter")
input()
print("Logged In")
inp_xpath_search = "//input[@title='Search or start new chat']"
input_box_search = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(inp_xpath_search))
```

```
error
Exception has occurred: TimeoutException
Message: 
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\whatsappp.py", line 16, in <module>
    input_box_search = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(inp_xpath_search))
```

Answer (score 0):

Timeout exception throw out when a specific condition is not satisfied. In this case is your driver can not find the element with xpath:

```
//input[@title='Search or start new chat']
```

Try to wrap explicit waiting with try catch to avoid execution shutdown